# Launchpad OpenID not working for login on Ask Ubuntu

Tags: support, login, launchpad

I can't log in here using my Launchpad ID.

I get ***Canceled*** on the identification page of AskUbuntu.

On the Launchpad, I get an ***Oops*** page with an message saying that the error was logged.

> Sorry, something just went wrong in Launchpad Login Service. We've recorded what happened, and we'll fix it as soon as possible. Apologies for the inconvenience. (Error ID 1821canistellaunchpad10)

Does the error come from Ask Ubuntu or Launchpad? Should I report it to Launchpad?